# $\mathrm{Ext}^1$-ordering on ${}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, bruhat-order

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional complex semisimple Lie algebra with Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$.
Let $W$ be the associated Weyl group and let $\Phi$ be its root system.
We write $\Phi^+$ for the set of positive roots in $\Phi$.

Fix a subset of simple roots $I$ and let $W_I$ be the corresponding standard parabolic subgroup of $W$, with longest element $w_I$ and root system $\Phi_I\subseteq \Phi$. Let $\Phi_I^+:=\Phi_I\cap\Phi^+$.

Define
$
\Lambda^+_I := \{\nu \in \mathfrak{h}^*  :  \langle\nu,\alpha^\lor\rangle \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \ \text{for all }\alpha \in \Phi^+_I\}.
$

Consider $\lambda \in \Lambda^+_I$ and assume $\lambda$ is integral. We define 
$
{}^IW := \{w\in W: w<s_\alpha w \ \text{for all }\alpha\in I\},
$
where $<$ is the Bruhat ordering on $W$.

Denote by $\Delta$ the simple system corresponding to the positive system $\Phi^+$ in $\Phi$. The orbit $W\cdot\lambda$
contains a unique $\mu\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ that is antidominant in the sense that 
$\langle \mu+\rho,\alpha^{\lor}\rangle\not\in\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ for all $\alpha\in \Phi^+$, where $\rho = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\alpha \in \Phi^+} \alpha$.

The set of singular simple roots associated to $\mu$ in $\Delta$ is defined by 
$
{\Sigma_\mu} : = \{\alpha\in \Delta: \langle\mu+\rho,\alpha^\lor\rangle=0\}.
$

The subgroup $W_{\Sigma_\mu} := \{w\in W: w(\mu+\rho)=\mu+\rho\}\subseteq W$ is then the isotropy group of $\mu$.

Let
$
{}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu} : = \{w\in {}^IW: w<ws_\alpha\in {}^IW\ \text{for all }\alpha\in {\Sigma_\mu}\},
$
where $<$ is the Bruhat ordering on $W$.

Let $M_I(\eta)$ be the parabolic Verma module with highest weight $\eta$ and $L(\eta)$ be its unique simple quotient.

From section 8.3 of [KOSTANT MODULES IN BLOCKS OF CATEGORY $O_S$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604336.pdf):

For $x<w$ in ${}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$. Define $c_I(x,w)=\dim \mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}\left(M_I(w_Ix\cdot\mu),L(w_Iw\cdot\mu)\right)$.

For $x, w \in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$, write $x \to_c w$ if $x < w$ in the Bruhat ordering, $c_I(x, w) \neq 0$ and there
is no $x < z < w$ in ${}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$ with $c_I(z, w) \neq 0$. Then define $\le_c$ as the ordering on ${}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$ generated by the covering relations $x \to_c w$. We call this ordering on ${}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$ the $\mathrm{Ext}^1$-ordering.

> I would like to know whether the sentences "**For any $w\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}-\{e\}$, there exists $x\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$ such that $x<w$, where $<$ is the Bruhat ordering on $W$.**" and "**For any $w\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}-\{e\}$, there exists $x\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$ such that $x<_cw$.**" are true or not?